# Xcode 7.3.1 won't install on mavericks 10.9.5

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to install the latest Xcode, 7.3.1, and I get this error message, "Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because OS X version 10.11 or later is required."  The thing is I have OS X 10.9.5, Mavericks.  Why is this happening?

Comment: "The thing is I have OS X 10.9.5, Mavericks" Yup, that is the thing.

Answer (score 2):

Because Xcode 7.3 requires at least OS X 10.11, and no longer supports 10.9.

Xcode 6.2 was the last version to support 10.9, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_5.0_-_6.x_.28since_arm64_support.29).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question:  "Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because OS X version 10.11 or later is required."

Apple does not allow newer versions of Xcode to be installed on older MacOS versions.

You need to upgrade your Macintosh to MacOS 10.11, which should be a free upgrade for you.

Comment: I have `macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5`, want to install `Xcode 7.3.1`, but I have the problem explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531863/xcode-7-3-1-cannot-be-opened-in-macos-mojave.