# Xcode 7.3.1 cannot be opened in MacOS Mojave

Tags: xcode7.3, macos-mojave

After updating from macOS High Sierra to Mojave and I successfully installed Xcode 7.3.1 but it cannot be opened. Does Mojave support Xcode 7?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue after upgrading to macOS Mojave. The only solution which I had to do is to download Xcode 8 and migrate to Swift 3.

Incase there're any alternatives, please share!